# Speed up row scanning for large datasets in Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

When issuing a simple query in spanner using primary index of the interleaving table for a split having millions of records then it takes long time to scan the table.

For instance `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE foo_key="bar"` where `foo_key` is the primary index of the interleaving table.
It scans 3,000,000 rows and it takes up to 40 seconds to resolve (please note that this question does not restrict to simple COUNT query, but any query where table scan is the bottleneck).

I'm thinking of that case in BigQuery where it will use multiple processes that get merged to speed up requests.What sounds confusing in spanner is that in the execution plan we can see that spanner performs a table scan with a single execution, then a distributed union of the rows. That makes me think it could use multiple processes as well.

Are there any ways for the scan process to be spread across multiple executions to speed up the table scan?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Spanner does not perform well as an analytics database - as you have seen - and so full table scans are not recommended.

Depending on your query, you may be able to limit to a key-range or multiple key-ranges to reduce the number of rows scanned, possibly in conjunction with an index...

I am not sure I understand your example query though:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE foo_key="bar"
```

(where foo_key is the primary index.)

This should only read a single row -- as you are specifying the primary key - and return either 1 or 0 depending on if the key exists.

Comment: This is not a full table scan, full table scan would perform on even more rows. As I said I already use a primary to limit number of rows scanned. I meant to say `foo_key` is the primary key of the interleaving table. My bad.

Comment: So you are scanning effectively all (or a subset of) child rows of a parent? Because of the co-location of data for parent and child tables, they will be on the same split, and so the scan can only use one node.

Comment: Ok, so if I used a different top interleaving table to spread them across more splits then it would allow the table scan to occur in multiple executions? We'll explore this solution. Wouldn't it impact performances of smaller sets of data as they would live in different splits? For instance most of the time we have less than 1000 rows to scan (if not less than 100), but as you can see sometimes we have a lot of them (milions)

Answer (score 1):

There exists **[Schema design best practices](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-design)** that will definetely help **make a difference** in **reducing the time your scan process takes.** They are as follows:

> - Choosing a primary key to prevent hotspots.
> - Limiting the row size.
> - Designing interleaved tables to prevent hotspots.
> - Using descending order for timestamp-based keys.
> - Using an interleaved index on a column whose value monotonically increases or decreases.

Also, the following **[link](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sql-best-practices)** will show you **best practices for constructing SQL statements for Cloud Spanner** to find efficient **[execution plans](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/query-execution-plans)**. **Using secondary indexes** to speed up queries or writing **efficient queries** for **joins and range key lookup** are among the few best practices listed on the previous documentation.

There is also the so-called **sharded counters approach** where a specific counter, such as likes for a given picture or *insert you specific use case here*, **consists of N shards/rows.** Not totally sure if applicable to your use case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for details, we already apply all those best practices here, but we still have big splits from times to time as you can see. Any links for the sharded counter, I'm not sure to know what it refers to?

Comment: Not totally sure if it applies to your Cloud Spanner case, nonetheless, here's the [sharded counter approach](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-sharded-counters-python).

I think the main point is to avoid using primary keys monotonically increasing.
This is achieved through [proper primary key election](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-design). The graphical description is pretty good.

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand what is sharded counter now. We already apply this, in some ways but here it would not solve the issue of having to scan lot of rows at once from a single split